# In a new version of an existing android app, can I change the permissions?

Tags: android, permissions

A while ago in our firm we release and android app on google play.
We would now like to send out a new version of that app with some small code changes, but also with some changes to the permissions.

In particular we want to add the following to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Can a new version of an app request more permissions than the previous version?
( I.e. will google play block the release?)

What will the user see when she installs the upgrade?

Thanks

Comment: You can change the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that yes !

Users will be prompted of the new permissions.